# Can't find APIM_ANALYTICS_DB script in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 analytics to change to oracle?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I can't find APIM_ANALYTICS_DB script in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 Analytics to change to Oracle db?
Is it automatically created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Analytics databases, it is not required to execute the database scripts to populate tables. You have to create only the database and point the particular database via the data source configurations in the `deployment.yaml` files (in `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/<profile>`) of each analytics profile.

For example, you can edit the `APIM_ANALYTICS_DB` section in `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml` to achieve this for the dashboard. Similar thing can be done for the worker as well.

```
- name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
  description: "The datasource used for APIM statistics aggregated data."
  jndiConfig:
    name: jdbc/APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
    definition:
      type: RDBMS
      configuration:
        jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE'
        username: 'root'
        password: '123'
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        minIdle: 5
        maxPoolSize: 50
        idleTimeout: 60000
        connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        connectionInitSql: alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
        validationTimeout: 30000
        isAutoCommit: false
```

In the 1st server startup of the Analytics server, tables will create itself. Please note that it is required to configure appropriate user credentials for the database user and the particular user should have database table creation permissions for the relevant database to generated tables.

For more information, refer [1].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-4-configure-analytics